# What does .comm alignment mean in assembly code of C program

Tags: memory-management, assembly, gnu

I have this C program.

```
#include<stdio.h>

char arr[65];
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile it with `gcc` on `linux` with following command:

`gcc -Wall -save-temps arrNewGlobal.c -o arnewGlobal`

I get following assembly code.

```
.file   "arrglobal.c"
.comm   arr,65,32 
.text
.globl  main
.type   main, @function
    ..........
```

As per `as` documentation, .comm allocated uninitialized block of memory of size 65 with alignment of 32 bits (which mean address will have 5 least significant equal to zero)

What I don't understand is if this address means starting address of this block of memory or each byte of this memory should have address with 5 least significant bits equal to zero (like each byte address make jumps)

Also just to make sure, this address is not physical address, instead it is a virtual address?

Answer (score 1):

> .comm name, size,alignment

The '**.comm**' directive allocates storage in the data section. The storage is referenced by the identifier **name**. 
**Size** is measured in bytes and must be a positive integer. Name cannot be predefined. 
**Alignment** is optional. If alignment is specified, the address of name is aligned to a multiple of alignment.

Yes the address is virtual address. Your paging mechanism takes care of mapping it to physical address like in any other case.

Answer (score 0):

That code means that 65 bytes aligned to 32 bytes/bits (4 bytes) (I don't know, honestly), but it definitely doesn't mean that every byte should be at address with 5 ls bits cleared. Just imagine - this array wouldn't be an array though - it wouldn't be continuous in memory.
What do u mean saying "physical" and "virtual" addresses?